# Android Preference Error ?? RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, preference

XML files has no recycler view but this error was happen

and I get an error

Attempt to invoke virtual method  'void
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'
on a null object reference

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Preference category">

    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/module_Type_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/module_Type_values"
        android:key="module_type"
        android:title="a" />

</PreferenceCategory>
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="Default value"
    android:key="current_mode"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:summary="default"
    android:title="aa" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and also error in this
onDestroyView(Unknown Source:0)
what is mean of Unknown Source: 0

Comment: your code and error are not related

Comment: show your LAYOUT xml file (and Java/Kotlin side), not preference declarations

Comment: To sum it up: your recyclerview is null!

Comment: It seems you have failed to initialize your recyclerview adapter.

Comment: my question is this, why fragment(preferenceFragmentCompat) attempt to invoke RecyclerView error. I never used RecyclerView in my project...

Comment: @snachmsm there just declaration preferenceList and editTextPreference in onCreatePreferences() just basic one

Comment: I found my error. In my PreferenceFragmentCompat() i have to override a onCreateRecyclerView. But i override onCreateview instead so they said i need a Recyclerview adapter